# Installing PostGIS extension to PostgreSQL with Stack Builder

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, mac, stackbuilder

I am trying to add the PostGIS extension to PostgreSQL. My efforts to add it to my existing Postgres application failed, so I uninstalled and reinstalled it.

I used the [EDB installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). Everything went fine with the install until I tried to add the PostGIS extension in Stack Builder. It was then that I got this error:

> It was not possible to perform the
> installation with administrator privileges
> (status: 4294907289).
> Please execute:
> sudo/tmp/h6trHS/postgis-pg13-3.0.2-1.
> osx.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64 --
> mode text
> as an alternative to achieve the
> same effect

I tried entering that command into terminal and got the following response:

> zsh: no such file or directory: sudo/tmp/h6trHS/postgis-pg13-3.0.2-1.
> zsh: no such file or directory: osx.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64

I've uninstalled PostgreSQL and reinstalled it multiple times. I've tried downloading different versions of it (weirdly the 14.1 install failed every time I tried, so this is with 13.5), but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to fix?

I am nearly coding-illiterate.

My computer is a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions on the PostGIS website to download and install PostGIS for macosx.  https://postgis.net/install/

> OSX
>
> A popular distribution particularly for newbies is Postgres.app. It
> includes generally latest version of PostgreSQL, PostGIS, and PLV8.
> Great for development and testing. Do not mix with other
> installations. Homebrew users can just run “brew install postgis” and
> tends to be a favorite for more advanced users since there are brew
> scripts for most of the popular PostgreSQL extensions, not always
> present in other Mac distributions.
>
> The EnterpriseDb OSX PostgreSQL combination from EnterpriseDB includes
> generally latest stable minor version of PostGIS.
>
> The builds from KyngChaos are a little dated but useful for older
> PostGIS versions. Read the instructions carefully. Do not mix with
> other installations.

Comment: That worked, thanks!